# A build problem when I build the substrate-node-template in windows10 system

Tags: substrate-node-template, compilation, windows

[image: an error]I have searching some solutions in the internet. However, I can't deal with my problem. I hope someone can help me to deal with this problem. Thank you very much.[image: my configuration]

Answer (score 1):

The way to resolve this is to use WSL on windows. Follow these instructions:

1. Install https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install, you'll be prompted for a reboot
2. Install ubuntu or a distro of your choice from the Microsoft store
3. When you have a WSL ready, `sudo apt update; sudo apt install -y cmake pkg-config libssl-dev git gcc build-essential git clang libclang-dev`. Also install rust, nightly, and add wasm32-unknown-unknown as targets
4. Finally compile your code.